# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cities' of undefined [Geocomplete]

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, geocomplete

I am using this plugin in Rails but still have a problem with error in title.

Definition of script:

```
script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&sensor=false>
```

Input text field:

```
<%= f.text_field :place, id: "cities", class: "form-control cities", type: "text" %>
```

Javascript load:

```
$("cities").geocomplete();
$.fn.geocomplete("cities");
```

I have done everything as described on GitHub but still cannot get it works. If I use `$("#cities").geocomplete();` the error is the same.

Please, can somebody help me?

Comment: Is this a typo `$("cities")` and `fn.geocomplete("cities");`?

Comment: @Зелёный What do you mean by that? On the GitHub of Geocomplete its written that first row is input (search in autocomplete) and second row gives you search result back: http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/ In Basic usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also add the `jquery.geocomplete.js` script inorder to make the geo-complete work.

Scripts:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<script src="jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>
```

You should load these two scripts, then call the function.

```
$("#cities").geocomplete();  // Option 1: Call on element.
```

[Here is the reference](https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/)

Comment: Actually I had geocomplete.js in application.js://= require geocomplete I am using geocomplete gem, but the error is still the same.

Comment: there is no need of two functions, you can call only one,
`$("#cities").geocomplete();`

Comment: also see the page source, and check if geocomplete js is loaded

Comment: Ok, there is a progress. Error is gone without second row, I can see Enter a location in the field, but autocomplete still doesn't work.

Comment: once type it in the browser console and check. `$("#cities").geocomplete();  `

Comment: I have found out that it works. But not in Bootstrap modal. So thank you for your answer :) Now I think I have to set z-index of that field.